# Impute missing values with mean of specific group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, na

I have data that roughly looks like this:

```
df <- dplyr::tibble(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5),
                    gender = c("m", "m", "w", "w", "w", "m", "m", "w"),
                    age_group = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2),
                    lab1 = c(NA, 3, 2, 3, NA, NA, 4, 1),
                    lab2 = c(5, 4, NA, NA, 1, NA, 3, 5))
# A tibble: 8 x 5
     id gender age_group  lab1  lab2
  <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 m              1    NA     5
2     1 m              1     3     4
3     2 w              2     2    NA
4     2 w              2     3    NA
5     3 w              2    NA     1
6     4 m              1    NA    NA
7     4 m              1     4     3
8     5 w              2     1     5
```

Of course, my true data is much more complex and bigger, but this example should be sufficient to explain what I want to do. It's all about impute the `NA` values for the columns `lab1` and `lab2`.
A simple method I could think of is to replace the `NAs` with `mean` values or `median` values with respect to the *whole population*. However, as I have the `gender` and `age group` of each person, I want to replace the missing values with the **mean of values that belong to the same gender and age group**.

So in the above example, the first missing value of `lab1` is from a person that is a `male` and is in `age_group 1`. So I want to impute the value with the **mean value of lab1** of all other rows where **gender is male and age_group==1 as well**.

Is there any way to achieve this with a **dplyr pipline** and in parallel for multiple lab values?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('lab'), ~replace(., is.na(.), mean(., na.rm = TRUE))), 
              .by = c(gender, age_group))

#    id gender age_group  lab1  lab2
#  <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 m              1   3.5     5
#2     1 m              1   3       4
#3     2 w              2   2       3
#4     2 w              2   3       3
#5     3 w              2   2       1
#6     4 m              1   3.5     4
#7     4 m              1   4       3
#8     5 w              2   1       5
```

Comment: that is indeed a sweet solution. Thanks man!